# Getting started with CMMI

Tags: cmmi

I'm a beginner in software engineering field thus I have difficulty to understand CMMI.
I'd be happy if you help me understanding the following questions.

- What does CMMI tell you about documentation in a project?
- What should we do in a CMMI about documentation?

Answer (score 1):

i think [CMMI for Development, Version 1.3](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/10tr033.pdf) can help you .
its about 480 pages , but at least reading the preface and introduction chapter are far more useful than reading those stupid wikipedia articles .

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 30 of the book, Software Engineering: A Practitioner's Approach has sufficient information about CMMI